# Inserting data to sqlite in objective c

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I want to insert some datas to sqlite manager. There is any error message in xcode console screen while inserting. But, I can not see datas in database file (mydataabase.sqlite) when open it. How can I solve this?

adding method in MyClass

```
 - (void) addCoffee {

NSArray *pathsArray=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *doumentDirectoryPath=[pathsArray objectAtIndex:0];
destinationPath=[doumentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mydatabase.sqlite"];
NSLog(@"database path %@",destinationPath);

database=nil;
if (sqlite3_open([destinationPath UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK) 
{
    NSLog(@"dataBaseOpen");
    // leak happens here, do stuff then call sqlite3_close(database), or move it out of the if/else block.
    if(addStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "insert into records(Date, Latitude, Longitude) Values(?, ?, ?)";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [Date UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_double(addStmt, 2, [Latitude doubleValue] );
        sqlite3_bind_double(addStmt, 3, [Longitude doubleValue] );
        }
        else 
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    }

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else
        //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
        recordID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

    //Reset the add statement.
    sqlite3_reset(addStmt);

}
else {
    sqlite3_close(database);
    NSLog(@"dataBaseNotOpen");
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while opening database '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

}   



}
```

sending data:

```
iDailyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (iDailyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

//Create a Coffee Object.
MyClass *coffeeObj = [[MyClass alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:0];
coffeeObj.Date = dateInString;
NSDecimalNumber *temp = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:first];
coffeeObj.Latitude = temp;
NSDecimalNumber *temp2 = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:second];
coffeeObj.Longitude = temp2;
[temp release];
coffeeObj.isDirty = NO;
coffeeObj.isDetailViewHydrated = YES;

//Add the object
[appDelegate addCoffee:coffeeObj];
```

Comment: You do check the sqlite file created in the Documents folder in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/{verison}/Applications/{app id} right?

Comment: I looked that path but I cant find. I running my application on device . Can I find device' s folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided what NSLog says.

You can access to the files of the your app on device via Organizer and check if you are writing to db.

Also test first on simulator, if it works there it has to work on device too in case that you didn't hardcoded some paths.